# How Can I Automate Running Pig Batch Jobs on Elastic MapReduce without Amazon GUI?

Tags: apache-pig, elastic-map-reduce

I have some pig batch jobs in .pig files I'd love to automatically run on EMR once every hour or so. I found a tutorial for doing that [here](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Elastic-MapReduce/2729), but that requires using Amazon's GUI for every job I setup, which I'd really rather avoid. Is there a good way to do this using Whirr? Or the Ruby Elastic-mapreduce client? I have all my files in s3, along with a couple pig jars with functions I need to use.

Comment: This question may have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as it focusses on suggested solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Though I don't know how to run pig scripts with the tools that you mention, I know of two possible ways:

1. To run files locally: you can use cron
2. To run files on the cluster: you can use OOZIE

That being said, most tools with a GUI, can be controlled via the command line as well. (Though setup may be easier if you have the GUI available).